# Typescript failing on adding jquery, can't resolve namespace Sizzle

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm new to Typescript and have been porting a decent sized codebase to use it, successfully until I had to include JQuery. Using webpack, this is in my main.ts:

`import $ from 'jquery';`

In the webpack output, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in /Users/jbd/app_maker/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts
(27,33): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

ERROR in /Users/jbd/app_maker/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts
(35,14): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

ERROR in /Users/jbd/app_maker/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts
(43,17): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Sizzle'.

ERROR in /Users/jbd/app_maker/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts
(29,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'sizzle'.

ERROR in /Users/jbd/app_maker/www/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'sizzle'.
```

Just installed @types/jquery tonight, which ironically seems to have added @types/sizzle itself. JQuery was working just fine with webpack on this codebase, so I gather the problem is in the type definition .d.ts files, but I don't know what the fix is.